# The proof of van der Corput inequality

Tags: inequality

$\newcommand{\lrp}[1]{\left(#1\right)}$
$\newcommand{\lrmod}[1]{\left|#1\right|}$

I am trying to understand the proof of the van der Corput inequality given [in Lemma 1 of this blog entry due to Tao](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/06/14/the-van-der-corputs-trick-and-equidistribution-on-nilmanifolds/#more-411). We will use the Big-O notation, whose definition can be found [here.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation)

> **Lemma. (Van der Corput Inequality).**
>   Let $a_1 a_2, a_3 , \ldots$ be a sequence of complex numbers bounded by magnitude $1$.
>   Then for any $1\leq H\leq N$ we have
>   $$
> \lrmod{ 
> \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n
> }
> \leq
> \lrp{
> \frac{1}{H}\sum_{h=0}^{H-1} \lrmod{ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_{n+h}\bar a_n}
> }^{1/2} + O\lrp{ \frac{H}{N}}
> $$

The proof Tao has provided proceeds as follows. It is easy to see that 
$$
\lrmod{
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_{n+h}
}
=
O\lrp{\frac{H}{N}}
$$
Therefore
$$
\frac{1}{H}\sum_{h=0}^{H-1}\lrmod{
\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n - \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_{n+h}
}
=
O\lrp{\frac{H}{N}}
$$
and hence by triangle inequality we have that
$$
\lrmod{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n - \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{H}\sum_{h=0}^{H-1} a_{n+h}}
=
O\lrp{\frac{H}{N}}
$$
Write
$$
x= \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N a_n \text{ and } y_n= \frac{1}{H} \sum_{h=0}^{H-1} a_{n+h}
$$
So the last equation becomes
$$
\lrmod{x- \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N y_n} = O\lrp{ \frac{H}{N}}
$$
Again by triangle inequality we have that
$$
|x| \leq  \lrmod{ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N y_n} + O\lrp{ \frac{H}{N}} \leq \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N |y_n| + O\lrp{ \frac{H}{N}}
$$
By Jensen's inequality we have
$$
\lrp{\frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N |y_n|}^2 \leq \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N |y_n|^2
$$
Thus we get
$$
|x| \leq \lrp{ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N |y_n|^2}^{1/2} + O\lrp{ \frac{H}{N}}
$$
which is nothing but
$$
\lrmod{ \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n} \leq \lrp{ \frac{1}{N} \sum_{n=1}^N \lrmod{\frac{1}{H} \sum_{h=0}^{H-1} a_{n+h}}^2}^{1/2} + O\lrp{ \frac{H}{N}}
$$
At this point Tao writes that ``Expanding out the square and rearranging a bit, we soon obtain the desired upper bound."
I am unable to follow this step. Can somebody please give some details here. *Also, if you can comment on what this inequality is trying to capture then please feel free to share.*

Comment: lemma 4: https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/03/28/254b-notes-1-equidistribution-of-polynomial-sequences-in-torii/

Comment: @mathworker21 I tried to follow the hint given by Tao but I still don't get it. Can you please provide some details. Thanks.

Comment: okay, see my answer below. It took a while to type, so I'd appreciate if you looked at it. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mistaking the inequality. Tao is saying that there is a constant $C > 0$ with $|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_n| \le C(\frac{1}{H}\sum_{h \le H} |\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_{n+h}\overline{a_n}|)^{1/2} + C\frac{H}{N}$.

Actually, I think there should be a  $C\frac{1}{H^{1/2}}$ on the right hand side as well (see the link I gave).

Based on where you got to, and using $\sqrt{x+y} \le \sqrt{x}+\sqrt{y}$, it suffices to show $$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} |\frac{1}{H}\sum_{h \le H} a_{n+h}|^2 \le \frac{2}{H}\sum_{h \le H} |\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_{n+h}\overline{a_n}|+O(\frac{1}{H})+O(\frac{H}{N}).$$

Merely by expanding the square, the left hand side is $$\frac{1}{H^2}\sum_{h_1,h_2 \le H} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_{n+h_1}\overline{a_{n+h_2}}.$$ The term $h_1 = h_2$ has contribution $$\frac{1}{H^2}\sum_{h \le H} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} |a_{n+h}|^2 = O(\frac{1}{H}),$$ so we can ignore it. We are left with

\begin{align*} 
\frac{2}{H^2}\sum_{1 \le h_1 < h_2 \le H} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} a_{n+h_1}\overline{a_{n+h_2}} &= \frac{2}{H^2}\sum_{1 \le h_1 < h_2 \le H} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=h_1+1}^{N+h_1} a_n\overline{a_{n+h_2-h_1}} \\ &= \frac{2}{H^2}\sum_{1 \le h_1 < h_2 \le H} \left[\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\overline{a_{n+h_2-h_1}} + O(\frac{H}{N})\right].
\end{align*}

The $O(\frac{H}{N})$ term merely comes out of the triple sum (since everything is averaged), so we can ignore it. We are left with $$\frac{2}{H^2} \sum_{1 \le h_1 < h_2 \le H} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\overline{a_{n+h_2-h_1}} = \frac{2}{H^2}\sum_{h \le H}\sum_{\substack{1 \le h_1 < h_2 \le H \\ h_2-h_2 = h}} \frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\overline{a_{n+h}}.$$

Now, we can pull out the sum in $n$ and note that the number of $1 \le h_1 < h_2 \le H$ with $h_2-h_1 = h$ is $H-h$ to get $$\frac{2}{H^2}\sum_{h \le H} (H-h)\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\overline{a_{n+h}},$$ which is upper bounded by $$\frac{2}{H^2}\sum_{h \le H} (H-h)\left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\overline{a_{n+h}}\right|,$$ which is of course upper bounded by $$\frac{2}{H}\sum_{h \le H} \left|\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^N a_n\overline{a_{n+h}}\right|,$$ as desired.

---

In regards to what this inequality is trying to capture. First, note that it holds in any Hilbert space, i.e. $||\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} v_n|| \le C(\frac{1}{H}\sum_{h \le H} ||\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} \langle v_{n+h},v_n \rangle||)^{1/2}+C\frac{1}{H^{1/2}}+C\frac{H}{N}$ (just go through the proof). Now suppose the $v_n$'s are mutually orthogonal. Then the left hand side is $\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}$, while the right hand side is $O(\frac{1}{H^{1/2}})+O(\frac{H}{N})$ (which actually shows the need for the $O(\frac{1}{H^{1/2}})$ term), where the $O(\frac{1}{H^{1/2}})$ term came from $\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} \langle v_n,v_n \rangle$, the "diagonal term" in the proof above. The point is that the Van der Corput inequality allows one to get good bounds on $||\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n \le N} v_n||$ when the $v_n$'s are "almost orthogonal" (the preceding sentence shows it specializes to actual orthogonality).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. I will go through it by tomorrow and respond.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly different proof. Let $a_1,\ldots, a_N$ be complex numbers (not necessarily of modulus $1$). Define $a_n=0$ for $n\leq0$ or $n>N$. For any $1\leq H\leq N$ we have that

$$H\sum^N_{n=1}a_n=\sum^{N+H-1}_{p=1}\sum^{H-1}_{h=0}a_{p-h}$$

By Cauchy-Schwartz
\begin{align}
H\Big|\sum^N_{n=1}a_n\Big| &\leq (N+H-1)^{1/2}\left(\sum^{N+H-1}_{p=1}\left|\sum^{H-1}_{h=0}a_{p-h}\right|^2\right)^{1/2}=(N+h-1)^{1/2}\left(\sum^{N+H-1}_{p=1}\left(\sum^{H-1}_{h=0}a_{p-h}\right)\left(\sum^{H-1}_{h=0}\overline{a_{p-h}}\right)\right)^{1/2}\\
&=(N+H-1)^{1/2}\left(\sum^{N+H-1}_{p=1}\left(\sum^{H-1}_{h=0}|a_{p-h}|^2+2\sum_{1\leq s<r\leq H-1}{\frak R}\big(a_{p-r}\overline{a_{p-s}}\big)\right)\right)^{1/2}\\
&=(N+H-1)^{1/2}\left(\sum^{N+H-1}_{p=1}\left(\sum^{H-1}_{h=0}|a_{p-h}|^2\right) + 2\sum^{N+H-1}_{p=1}\sum_{1\leq s<r\leq H-1}{\frak R}\big(a_{p-r}\overline{a_{p-s}}\big)\right)^{1/2}
\end{align}
The nonzero terms in the sum
$$S:=\sum^{N+H-1}_{p=1}\sum_{1\leq s<r\leq H-1}{\frak R}\big(a_{p-r}\overline{a_{p-s}}\big)$$
are of the form $a_n\overline{a_{n+h}}$ where $1\leq n\leq N-1$ and $1\leq h\leq H-1$. For fixed $n=p-r$ and $h=r-s$ in $\{1,\ldots N-1\}$ and $\{1,\ldots, H-1\}$ respectively, the pairs $(s, r)$ with $0\leq s<r\leq H-1$ that yield $a_n\overline{a_{n+h}}$ are $(0,h),(1,h+1),\ldots (H-1-h,h+H-1-h)$ and for each such pair, there is a unique $1\leq p\leq N+H-1$ such that $n=p-r$. Hence, the term $a_n\overline{a_{n+h}}$ appears $H-h$ times in $S$. Consequently
Hence
\begin{align}
\Big|\sum^N_{n=1}a_n\Big|\leq (N+H-1)^{1/2}\left(H\sum^N_{n=1}|a_n|^2+ 2\sum^{H-1}_{h=1}(H-h)\sum^{N-h}_{n=1}{\frak R}\big(a_n\overline{a_{n+h}}\big)\right)^{1/2}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}.
Inequality \eqref{one} is van der Corput's inequality. It can also be rewritten as
\begin{align}
\Big|\frac1N\sum^N_{n=1}a_n\Big|^2\leq \frac{N+H-1}{NH}\left(\frac1N\sum^N_{n=1}|a_n|^2\,+\,2\sum^{H-1}_{h=1}\frac{H-h}{H}\frac{N-h}{N}\frac1{N-h}\sum^{N-h}_{n=1}{\frak R}(a_n\overline{a_{n+h}})\right)
\end{align}